# Improving SEO on Answers for Increased Findability

Tags: discussion, answers, seo

Great answers [answer technical questions helpfully](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2009/02/17/answering-technical-questions-helpfully.aspx), a necessity for answers that become reputation bedrocks.

But **mother lode** answers benefit from a near continuous stream of page views resulting in proportional upvotes. As far as I can tell, the best predictors of this kind of traffic are in the *question*:

- Well formed title
- Clearly written
- Not localized
- **Will it be asked again?**

With this in mind, **how could one SEO their great answer to mitigate the effects of the wimpily-written question it addresses?** I'm thinking of things like generically rephrasing the question, using `<h1>Headings</h1>`, etc.

It's frustrating to have some of your best answers collecting dust in oblivion. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`https://www.google.com/search?q=increase+answer+findability`--Your question is the first result. Good title!

From a technical viewpoint, optimizing a question or answer for search engine optimization requires:

1. A simple, *short* title including the main platforms/technologies/etc that the post is in reference to.
   (In an *answer* I think that your last suggestion would be perfect--wrapping relevant text with header tags. (But let's not go over-board!)).
2. Updating the post with more information as you continue to research the problem or perhaps link to another SO Q/A that you came across, mentioning a similar or related scenario.
3. Ensure correct and accurate [tags](/questions/tagged/tags) are in place (provided you have the re-taging privilege).
4. Share links to the post.
   (There's some badges in it for you too here! (Once again--let's not go over-board!))
5. Spell check. Spell checking your posts is a matter of the the utmost impotence!

Comment: @Lix Merging the answer into the question is kind of ... bad. It doesn't help anything and only makes it more difficult to track what's going on with this question. If a different answer turns up, it'll happen regardless of whether your answer exists. If not, your bounty will be lost either way.

Answer (score 1):

Missing from the accepted answer, but arguably important, is finding duplicate questions and getting them closed with a pointer to the canonical.

This presupposes that the question *you* answered is suitable to be the canonical, but the workaround should be obvious - if your answer is collecting dust on a question which *itself* is a duplicate, (delete your answer there and) post it as an answer to the canonical; *then* vote to close the worse question as a duplicate of the canonical you found.

(This works best if you have a gold badge in a relevant tag, which gives you the privilege to single-handedly close duplicates, AKA hammer them. If you don't, you might want to find a chat room where you can coordinate with other users in the tag you are interested in, or for smaller sites perhaps the site's main - and quite possbly only - chat room. Not all chat communities are interested in curation, so maybe check with a chat room owner for room policies first. For Stack Overflow, there's always [SOCVR](https://socvr.org).)

This isn't traditional "SEO" in the strictest sense, but if successfully implemented, you are driving traffic to the question you want to promote by way of users finding the duplicates as useful signposts towards the destination question.